# R - delete rows providing a specific combination of values

Tags: r, subset

I have a list of 100 objects and I create all possible pairs of them using

```
pairs <- t(combn(my_objects, 2))
```

But any object of group A can not be combined to any object of group B.
Means if

```
group_A <- c(5:10)
group_B <- c(50:55)
```

a pair of 6 and 55 should be deleted, no matter in which row they are. A combination of 5 and 6 is ok. 
How can I check each row for one of these "forbidden" pairs and delete it? I tried the `%in%` but I don know how to use it for multiple objects.

**EDIT**

My real problem is like this:
I have a list of 75 characters, A1 ... A75. They should be combined to pairs. But one of group_A (5...10) should never be combined to one of group_B (50...55).

Second step: It can be, that an entry of a row in `pairs`can be: `A1.A8 - A2.A.12.A51`. This pair should also be deleted.

My data frame is:

```
 pairs <- cbind (c("A1", "A9.A3", "A5", "A52.A12", "A8"), 
               c("A76.A14", "A50", "A2.A7", "A70", "A50.A51"))

group_A <- c("A5", "A6" "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10")
group_B <- c("A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55")
```

My aim - delete all combinations of items of group_A and group_B from the `pairs`data frame. So that `pairs` =

```
     [,1] [,2]     
[1,] "A1" "A76.A14"
[2,] "A5" "A2.A7"  
[3,] "A52.A12" "A70"
```

Comment: Plese show a reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 0):

We can use `expand.grid` with `paste` to create a `vector` of combinations, check whether these elements are there `%in%` the `vector` created with `combn`, negate (`!`) and subset the 'pairs' with this logical vector.

```
v1 <- combn(length(my_objects), 2, FUN = paste, collapse=" ")
pairs[!v1 %in% do.call(paste, expand.grid(group_A, group_B)),]
```

Comment: hm, no somehow it's not working. `pairs`has still the same length and the forbidden combinations extist

Comment: @Miguel123  I created `set.seed(24);my_objects <- sample(1:200, 100, replace=FALSE)` and it is working for me `dim(pairs)
#[1] 4950    2` and `dim(pairs[!v1 %in% do.call(paste, expand.grid(group_A, group_B)),])#[1] 4914    2`

Comment: hm ok, my objects have always a letter as prefix. might that be the problem?

Comment: @Miguel123  If your `my_objects` is a vector of length 100, it should work

Comment: no it's not. It is a list of 75 chars. I tried to ask the question as simplified as possible so that others might see similarities to their problem. sorry if that was incorrect. I will edit my question and add my real problem

Comment: I don't know what to do. I added my real problem maybe that helps to understand me?

Comment: is it now clear? I am still trying to compare a group of char with %in%. do you think that's a way to go?

Comment: @Miguel123 Suppose your `group_A <- paste0("A", 5:10); group_B <- paste0("B", 50:55)` then it should work.

Comment: thanks. yes, but I got rid of the "A" using `pairs <- gsub("A", "", pairs[] )`. However I can not deal with the `.` that appear in some entries of `pairs`

Comment: @Miguel123  I am not sure what you  are after `gsub("A\\.", "", pairs)` will get rid of the `.`

Comment: no, I mean the entries in `pairs` can be 1.12 or 3.28, as a combination of item code 1 and 12 (or 3 and 28). I have to respect this and a combination of `A1.A8 - A2.A.12.A51`should also be deleted. Check what I wrote to "second step" in the edited question :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not very elegant, but (I think) it does what you want: for each row, split the entries in each column by character '.', then check if there is any overlap with group_A or group_B, if so, add the row index to a vector of to-be-removed rows:

```
rm_idx <- c()
for (r in 1:nrow(pairs)) {  # for each row of pairs...
  pair_A <- unlist(strsplit(pairs[r,1],'[.]')) # split first element by '.'
  pair_B <- unlist(strsplit(pairs[r,2],'[.]')) # split second elemnt by '.'
  l_A <- length(intersect( group_A,  pair_A)) # elements of group_A in pair_A
  l_B <- length(intersect( group_B,  pair_B)) # elements of group_A in pair_A
  if (l_A > 0 & l_B > 0) { # if there is overlap in both entries of that row --> remove
    rm_idx <- c(rm_idx, r)
  }
}
new_pairs <- pairs[-rm_idx,]
```

Alternatively, you can create a regular expression that can be used with `grepl` to find any occurrence of an element of, say, `group_A` in a string:

```
# concatenate vector of strings (with '|'), creating a regular expression for
# searching for any of them (using grep/grepl)
grp2reg <- function (g) {
  paste(g, collapse ='|')
}

# append dot to string (or each of a vector of strings)
add_dot <- function(g) {
  paste(g, '.', sep='')
}

# find strings from group_A/group_B in first/second column of pairs
idx_A <- grepl(grp2reg(add_dot(group_A)), add_dot(pairs[,1]) )
idx_B <- grepl(grp2reg(add_dot(group_B)), add_dot(pairs[,2]) )

# remove rows with a match in both columns
pairs_new <- pairs[!(idx_A & idx_B),]
```

Note that appending '.' to all strings is necessary here to avoid "finding", say, `A5` in `A50`. So, the regular expression for `group_A` is actually `"A5.|A6.|A7.|A8.|A9.|A10."`, and dots are also appended to the elements of `pairs` (to find, say, `A5.` in `A50.A5.`).

Comment: Hi @Miguel123, does this answer your question or not? In either case, a reaction from your side would be expected.